# Can abilities like misfortune be used on nat 1/20?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

[This related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181978/23058) about abilities that require seeing dm rolls got me wondering about the **before the results of the roll are revealed** part. Since natural 1's and 20's are automatically failures and successes on attacks and saving throws, could the ability affect either?